# After I update my student.Id it refuses to be added to my Hashtable

Tags: c#, foreach, hashtable

In a lesson on hashtables, the online teacher lightly suggests trying to update a "students ID", represented as student.Id in foreach loop, depending on an instance where two IDs are identical.

I tried to make foreach loop, to check with the metod ContainsKey() and then executs an update or adds the student.Id to the hashtable. The problem i've found is the student.Id gets updated, e.g. ID 2 becomes 3 because 2 was already added to the list, but refuses to add it to this list thereafter.

I'm thinking i've overlooked something obvious?

```csharp
static void Main(string[] args)
{

            Hashtable studentsTable = new Hashtable();

            Student[] students = new Student[5];
            students[0] = new Student(1, "Maria", 98);
            students[1] = new Student(2, "Bob", 62);
            students[2] = new Student(1, "Mary", 90);
            students[3] = new Student(4, "Eric", 88);
            students[4] = new Student(5, "Clint", 72);


            foreach(Student student in students)
            {
                
                if(!studentsTable.ContainsKey(student.Id))
                {
                    studentsTable.Add(student.Id, student);
                    Console.WriteLine("Student with Id{0} was added!.", student.Id);
                }
                else if (studentsTable.ContainsKey(student.Id))
                {
                    do
                    {

                    student.Id += 1;

                    // this write line was to check that the id was being updated   

                    Console.WriteLine(student.Id);

                    } while (studentsTable.ContainsKey(student.Id));

                    // same as above comment

                    Console.WriteLine(student.Id);

                    studentsTable.Add(student.Id, student);
                }
                else
                 {
                 Console.WriteLine("Sorry, A student with the same ID: {0}, already Exists.", student.Id);
                 }


            }


        }

        class Student
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public float GPA { get; set; }

            public Student(int id, string name, float GPA)
            {
                this.Id = id;
                this.Name = name;
                this.GPA = GPA;
            }

        }
```

Comment: why you need `do... while` loop in `else if`?

Comment: if you want to update you should do `studentsTable[student.Id] = student`

Comment: I am simply did not got the above logic, why you need to increment by 1 also why `do...while` is needed and also the `else if  {}` condition does not make sense

Comment: Looks fine to me

Comment: @Sohan hash table IDs  need to be unique

Comment: *refuses to add it to this list thereafter* - take care to use exact and precise terms. Your code contains a List, but when you say "list" I suspect you mean "the hash table" - potentially confusing to call it a list, in this context

Comment: You believed _"refuses to add"_, because you didn't print _"Console.WriteLine("Student with Id{0} was added!.", student.Id);"_ after you added it to the hashtable.

Comment: @Chetan - Learning. I can see now it wasn't necessary.

Comment: @ shingo - you were right.  I'm slightly embarrassed, but at least I got to read some useful comments. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simplify your logic to:

```
    foreach(Student student in students)
    {
        
        while(studentsTable.ContainsKey(student.Id)){
          student.Id++;
        }

        studentsTable.Add(student.Id, student);
        Console.WriteLine("Student with Id{0} was added!.", student.Id);
        
    }
```

but I don't see a problem with it as is. A hash table ID must be unique so while there is already a student in the table with the same ID as the one we want to add, we increment the id of the student we are trying to add and check again, until we find an ID not in the table. In practice this means the second student with ID 1 will have the Id bumped to 3 before they can be added. If you printed the table at the end of the foreach would see 1,2,3,4,5 (well, hashtables aren't ordered so you might see any order, but you'd see 5 unique IDs and Mary would be 3)

Incidentally, and an interesting point for sakes of learning about reference types, whether you printed out the list or the hash table, you would see that in each one Mary has had their ID updated to 3. This is because there is only ever one Mary in memory, so updates to the memory data itself mean that all things that have a reference to Mary (the list, the hash table, any temporary loop variable) all experience the update because that are multiple references to one block of data, like multiple shortcuts to one original file

Note, it's incredibly unlikely your `else` logic will ever be used, so I removed it

Comment: Caius Jard

Thank you, I inserted your code and it seems to have solved my problem. It was certainly a more efficient way to approach the problem.  That being said, I couldn't find why it wasn't working.  I printed the Id to see if / where it was updating, and it was, but then it wasn't being added to the Hashtable. Perhaps @shingo was correct, I'll play around with it some more. 

True, my else logic was useless by the time I got that far in editing my loop to where it was when I shared it.  I'll try to be more efficient for myself, and when sharing code on the site.  

Thank you again!